# Im new to programming and im trying to run this code on python but ive done something wrong can someone fix my code i cant seem to get it right

Tags: if-statement, while-loop

```
count=0
while count < 3:
Username = input('Username: ')
Password = input('Password: ')
numAttempts = 3
     if Password=='123' and Username=='admin':
         print('Successfully logged in')
     elif:
         print('Invalid username and password!')
         count += 1
     else numAttempts > 3:
         print("Account has been blocked")
```

File "", line 8
if Password=='123' and Username=='admin':
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Answer (score 0):

In python, indents matter. You would need to tab everything after the

```
while count < 3:
```

Any conditional or loop statement needs to be indented after. It's also important for the tabs to be consistent (IE, using the tab key or same number of spaces).

You also look like you have your logic flipped with your else and elif statement.

Also, you numAttempts should probably start at 0, and you need to update this in the else clause.
This should get you started.

```
count=0
while count < 3:
    Username = input('Username: ')
    Password = input('Password: ')
    numAttempts = 3
    if Password=='123' and Username=='admin':
        print('Successfully logged in')
    elif numAttempts > 3:
        print("Account has been blocked")
    else:
        print('Invalid username and password!')
        count += 1
```